# Finding Dependencies Among Common Lisp Files

Tags: dependencies, common-lisp, asdf

The straightforward way to define an ASDF system involves specifying the dependencies among the component files. Given a (moderately large) collection of common lisp files for a working program, is there a way to easily work out the interfile dependencies to put in an `asdf:defsystem` specification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, you should invest some thought into the dependencies between files while writing them.  This also helps to structure your code in general.

For most small programs, just bringing them into some working order and then specifying `:serial t` should be sufficient.

ASDF's [package-inferred-system](https://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf/The-package_002dinferred_002dsystem-extension.html) turns the system composition from files on its head, in a way.  Anyway, some people seem to like it.